# SecurityException: Unsupported path /storage/emulated/999/Download/somefile.pdf

Tags: android, securityexception, runtime-permissions

I am trying to download some .pdf file from the server to `download` folder

This exception is thrown randomly on some device

Xiomi running android (8,7,6) : 97% crashes only in this device

Storage runtime permission have been given and it works

What I figure out is some device doesn't work even after runtime permission

**file_path.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="images"
        path="images/" />
    <external-files-path
        name="share"
        path="share/" />
    <external-files-path
        name="reminder_images"
        path="reminder_images/" />
</paths>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

**StackTrace**

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path /storage/emulated/999/Download/Somefile.pdf
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2013)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderProxy.java:476)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1555)
       at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:1163)
       at com.esafirm.rxdownloader.RxDownloader.download(RxDownloader.java:83)
       at com.esafirm.rxdownloader.RxDownloader.download(RxDownloader.java:60)
       at in.okcredit.app.ui.account.AccountActivity.onReportGenerated(AccountActivity.java:320)
       at in.okcredit.app.ui.account.AccountPresenter$1.onSuccess(AccountPresenter.java:118)
       at in.okcredit.app.ui.account.AccountPresenter$1.onSuccess(AccountPresenter.java:111)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:81)
       at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:119)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: May be you should try using file provider.

Comment: already using it . please see updated post

Comment: You also need to add some code inside `<provider>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Did you add that?

Comment: @ Ajay Mehta - Rlogica : yes

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-3/help/access-to-emulated-999-storage-t3709299

Comment: I am facing the same issue. was this resolved?

Comment: @shivani tiwari : NO

Comment: @karthikkolanji Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @ pavel163 : this is because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901955/dual-apps-cant-access-storage-path-storage-emulated-999-download-somefile-pdf