# Dual apps can't access storage path /storage/emulated/999/Download/somefile.pdf

Tags: android, android-securityexception

I am trying to download a file from server to `Download` folder of andorid

As expected it is working fine

**Problem**

When user clones my app (dual app) , the cloned app (2nd app)  throws **SecurityException: Unsupported path /storage/emulated/999/Download/somefile.pdf**

**Research**

Device : Redmi 5

App : File Manager (system app)

I found 2 options

1. Internal Storage
2. Storage for dual apps (it also has Download folder & other apps folder like Whatsapp)

Still my app throws **SecurityException**

Answer (score 1):

This is because android dual apps creates the new app instance separate from the normal file storage (kind of like a secure space) in this same way your original app won't be able to access the files of the cloned app. So in theory to make you. downloads function work again you need to find out where the new app instance has been cloned to (varies from device manufacturer) and then set that has the download location.
Hope I Helped!